# Is the replacement of a foreach loop with Iterable.forEach purely cosmetic?

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, java-8

My question concerns the Java foreach loop, introduced in Java 5, and `Iterable.forEach()`, introduced in Java 8.

Let's say that a program exists with a List of String values, and the function of that program is to iterate over each individual string and use it as a method parameter.

Such a program could look like this as of Java 5:

```java
for (String s : stringList) {
    doSomething(s);
}
```

However, with the introduction of `Iterable.forEach()` in Java 8, such a program could look like this:

```java
stringList.forEach(this::doSomething);
```

My question is, is there any reason to use `Iterable.forEach()` instead of the foreach loop beyond the saving of a couple lines?

Comment: If `doSomething` throws a checked exception, you then have to catch it explicitely...

Comment: @Tunaki It may not have been clear, but I meant to imply that doSomething is a safe method with no thrown exceptions.

Comment: It makes more of a difference if you are using a parallel stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing a `forEach` makes the action to be performed on the elements pluggable and very flexible. It can be an immediate lambda, a MethodHandle or even a MethodHanlde dynamically composed from a static portion of behavior and a runtime-defined part of it. Internally, the creation of an explicit `Iterator` object may be avoided. Otherwise, you can, of course, simulate the same behavior by an external loop. This might not look so nice though.

Comment: Excellent answer, and exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: @Deadshot It also has some significant limitations compared to the for-each loop.  You cannot use nonlocal control flow (break/continue) out of the action; you cannot access uplevel mutable locals; and you cannot throw checked exceptions even if the enclosing method declares them.  One does not replace the other.

Answer (score 5):

Here are 3 differences to consider between the two:

- Lambdas can not capture non-final variables.
- A `forEach` does not allow for `break`/`continue`.
- Checked exceptions must be caught *within* a passed lambda (since the type is [`Consumer<...>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html)).

```
List<MyClass> list = ...;

MyClass mc = null;

for(MyClass e : list) {
    if(e.test("bla")) {
        mc = e;
        break;
    }
}               

list.forEach(e -> {
    if(e.test("bla")) {
        mc = e; // Does not compile
        break; // Also, does not compile
    }
});
```

```
void method() throws Exception {        
    ...
    for(MyClass e : list) {
        ...
        throw new Exception("Oops");
    }

    list.forEach(e -> {
        ...
        throw new Exception("Oops"); // Error: unhandled exception
    });
}
```

Comment: You forgot also: checked exceptions (even if the enclosing method is declared to throw them).

Comment: @BrianGoetz Thanks, I added an example :)

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental benefit is that of *internal iteration* that you can utilize with `forEach` should the library decide to do it. When using the enhanced for loop (`for x : xs`), you insist on *external iteration*.

The idea is that you want some function to take every element of a list (or `Iterable`) and do something with it. The non-functional (traditional in Java) is to iterate over the list *in your code* and do it. This is called *external iteration*. This forces sequential execution.

With Java 8, you could create and pass lambda expression. So, you pass the behavior or function that accepts the element. Thus, you relinquish the control over iteration and let the list implementation (library code, so to speak) take care of iteration, possibly parallelizing the efforts.

Comment: Interesting. [The contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) does indeed allow for other orders if documented.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Java8 API you can do things like

```
stringList.stream ().filter(...).map(...).forEach(...)
```

Which can many times be cleaner and less error prone than just doing the same transformationsize and filtering inside a for each for loop.

Comment: Great answer, but not necessarily for this question.